# Leaflet GeoCSV popups are not being displayed

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, csv, html

I am using the Leaflet [GeoCSV plug in](https://github.com/joker-x/Leaflet.geoCSV) to try and add markers with popups to my map.
With the help of [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/436507/loading-of-local-csv-file-blocked-by-cors-policy-in-leaflet), I have been able to add the markers to the map, but I still want to add a popup to the those markers.

I tried using code from the previously mentioned post and used one of the examples of the plug in and played around with it, but I did not have any success with that.

The code I used to declare how the markers should be added (works for adding the markers but not the popups):

```
(function() {                                                                             
  'use strict';            
  var blob = new Blob([csvContent], { type: 'text/plain' });
  var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  $.get(blobUrl, function(csvContents) {
    var geoLayer = L.geoCsv(csvContents, {firstLineTitles: true, fieldSeparator: ';'});
    map.addLayer(geoLayer);
  });
})();
```

Othe Code I played around with (example from plug in):

```
L.geoCsv(null,{
  titles: ['lat', 'lng', 'popup'],
  fieldSeparator: ';',
  lineSeparator: '\n',
  deleteDobleQuotes: true,
  firstLineTitles: false,
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    var popup = '';
    for (var clave in feature.properties) {
      var title = geo_csv.getPropertyTitle(clave);
      popup += '<b>'+title+'</b><br />'+feature.properties[clave]+'<br /><br />';
    }
    layer.bindPopup(popup);
  }
});
```

My currnet csv file:

```
var csvContent = `lat;lng;title
52;8;test
8;52;test2`;
```

Note that the csv is converted to a js file to get around CORS policy.

Comment: So you want to display `title` value in you popup?

Comment: yes, so one popup says "test" and the other one "test2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeoCSV plugin returns data from additional columns (besides `lat` and `lng`) of CSV file as feature properties.

Relevant part of code to add popup with content from `title` column would then look like this:

```
var geoLayer = L.geoCsv(csvContents, {
  firstLineTitles: true,
  fieldSeparator: ';',
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.title);
  }
});
```