# How to add GeoJSON file to Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, geojson, html

I am new to JavaScript, HTML, and Leaflet. I would like to add a polygon to my Leaflet map.

Here is where I store the file. I want to use this file and don't want to add thousands of coordinates to my HTML. This file is stored locally and I do not know if that is an issue.
T:\EY\FP.geojson

Here is what the HTML code looks like.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin=""/>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" style="height: 500px; width: 100%;"></div>
  <script>
    // Initialize the map and set its view to Chicago
    var map = L.map('map').setView([41.881832, -87.623177], 11);

   var streetLayer = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
     attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
   });

   streetLayer.addTo(map);

      // add the GeoJSON file to the map (attempt 1# this part does not work)
      var geojson = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("T:\\EY\\FP.geojson", {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
          layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
        }
      }).addTo(map);

     // add the GeoJSON file to the map (attempt 2# this part also does not work)
     L.geoJSON("T:\\EY\\FP.geojson").addTo(map);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a sample of what the GeoJSON file looks like.

```
{
    "type" : "FeatureCollection",
    "name" : "FP",
    "features" : [
        {
            "type" : "Feature",
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Polygon",
                "coordinates" : [
                    [
                        [ -88.2635070004, 41.4695240004 ],
                        [ -87.1111620005, 41.4695240004 ],
                        [ -87.1111620005, 42.1542919999 ],
                        [ -88.2635070004, 42.1542919999 ],
                        [ -88.2635070004, 41.4695240004 ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties" : {
                "COUNTY" : "Cook County, IL",
                "OBJECTID" : 1
            }
        },
        {
            "type" : "Feature",
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Polygon",
                "coordinates" : [
                    [
                        [ -88.2614680002, 41.2015459998 ],
                        [ -87.5255909999, 41.2015459998 ],
                        [ -87.5255909999, 41.72893 ],
                        [ -88.2614680002, 41.72893 ],
                        [ -88.2614680002, 41.2015459998 ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties" : {
                "COUNTY" : "Will County, IL",
                "OBJECTID" : 2
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I've updated the code with my attempt.

Comment: See answer at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/436507/loading-of-local-csv-file-blocked-by-cors-policy-in-leaflet

Comment: I was hoping the fact that I was using a local file would not be an issue. I'll try to create a webpage and place the geojson file on a server. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading of local CSV file blocked by CORS policy in Leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/436507/loading-of-local-csv-file-blocked-by-cors-policy-in-leaflet)

Comment: I plan to set up a local server.